# How to create an zip file which contains gzip file in java?

Tags: java, zip, gzip

i am able to generate zip/gzip using GZIPOutputStream/ZipOutputStream

but no clue how to use zipentry for a gzip file

thanks

Comment: Put the code you had tested so far, will help you get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

there is no zipentry for gzip because the gzip format does not support multiple entries.  hence, you often see files as `".tar.gz"` or `".tgz"` which is the combination of two formats: "tar" (for sticking multiple files together) and "gzip" (for compressing them).

UPDATE:

if you want to generate a gzip file within a zip file, then you need to wrap the GZIPOutputStream around the ZipOutputStream (after calling `.putNextEntry`).  just make sure that you *don't* call `close()` on the GZIPOutputStream, just call `.finish()`.

Comment: yes, i understand that gzip file means single file, just want to know how can generate an zip file which contains gzip file,  thx anyway